# Entity associations

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-relationship, concept

i started to read Entity Framework Book.
in first part of book it describes entity and object similarities and differents.
it writes :

> Each entity has associations with
>   other entities.

what is the meaning of associations with other entities ? is that like relation ?
associations in my language means something like community(!).
so i can't Understand what does it mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it means relation. Each entity can have association / relation to other entities which allows some advanced concepts like loading related entities by single query, building complex queries or loading realted entities on demand.

Example:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Here we have two entities related in one-to-many relation. Both entities have navigation property to their related entities.